# Can we set CustomLayouts().Preserved = msoCFalse for all layouts in powerpoint using vba?

Tags: vba, powerpoint

Can we set all layouts of active presentation to .Preserved = msoCFalse?

The code for 1 layout :

```
ActivePresentation.Designs(1).SlideMaster.CustomLayouts(i).Preserved = msoCFalse
```

where i= layout index number.

So is there any way to do like All.Preserved = msoCFalse? or any better way to do the same?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop them performing the action on each;

```
Dim i As Long
With ActivePresentation.Designs(1).SlideMaster
    For i = 1 To .CustomLayouts.Count
        .CustomLayouts(i).Preserved = msoCFalse
    Next
End With
```

Comment: ya i know that but is there any other way to do without using any loop. like one line code. Because in my code there are already may loops are running so i am trying to avoid another loop for it.

Comment: No, not that I'm aware of. There is nothing wrong with looping, even if there were a single method it would itself still have to loop internally as its something at effects multiple things.